# how to back to previous destination programatically using navigation controller in Android?

Tags: android, android-navigation, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

I have login process like the image below:

[image]

the user will be navigated from login screen (in the middle) to change password screen (in the right) using the code below:

```
 val changePassword = LoginUsingEmailFragmentDirections.actionToChangePasswordFragment()
Navigation.findNavController(fragmentView).navigate(changePassword)
```

I want if the user successfully change the password, I want to make the user back to login screen programatically.

If I use the old way navigation using a lot of activities, then I usually using `finish()`

I little bit confused what is the right way to achieve this. do I need to make action first in the graph and then using the similar code like above ? or is there any more convenient or better way to do this ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can navigate up to login screen on button click listener like below:

```
btn.setOnClickListener{
 Navigation.findNavController(fragmentView).navigateUp()
}
```